# url convention to retrieve a field of a model?

Tags: rest, tastypie

Is there a preferred url scheme for a field in a resource?

I could create a thread resource and use the following url to retrieve thread.posts where thread.id = 8

```
/api/v1/thread/8/posts/
```

Or I could retrieve the same set of posts by using a post resource

```
/api/v1/post/thread_id__eq=8
```

`post` has foreign key to `thread`.

Are there preferred way of doing this? (better url scheme or tastypie convention?)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit opinionated, but for me the first option would be the preferred one. Why?

- Structured.
- Doesn't expose and depend on internal implementation/data scheme.
- Way easier to extend.
- It's way more readable.
- Assuming the second option passes the query in `GET` parameters, the payload is not usually logged by web servers (like nginx).